# How to get array of deleted walls from maze generation code Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maze

I am trying to get out an array of all the deleted walls from this maze generation code. Can't seem to make it work, when I ask it to print it will only give me the entire maze grid, and not the specific walls I'm asking for.

```
MazeGen2[m_, n_] := 
  Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity, 
    unvisited = Tuples[Range /@ {m, n}], maze, mazearray = {}, 
    mazeA},
   (*unvisited=Delete[unvisited,{{1},{2},{Length[
   unvisited]-1},{Length[unvisited]}}];*)
   (*Print[unvisited];*)

   maze = {{{{#, # - {0, 1}}, {#, # - {1, 0}}}} & /@ 
      unvisited, {{{0, n - 1}, {0, 0}, {m - 1, 
        0}}}};(*This generates the grid*)
   Print[maze];
   {unvisited = DeleteCases[unvisited, #];
      (*Print[unvisited];*)
      Do[
       If[MemberQ[unvisited, neighbor], 
        maze = DeleteCases[
          maze, {#, neighbor - {1, 1}} | {neighbor, # - {1, 1}}, {5}]
        (*mazeA=Flatten[AppendTo[mazearray,
        maze]];*)
        ; #0@neighbor],
       {neighbor, 
        RandomSample@{# + {0, 1}, # - {0, 1}, # + {1, 0}, # - {1, 
            0}}}
       ]
      } &@RandomChoice@unvisited;

   Flatten[maze]
   ];
```

Comment: I'm far too lazy to cut and paste a snippet which includes commented-out code whose presence just makes your function more difficult to understand.

Comment: I'm too lazy even to read @HighPerformanceMark's comment

Comment: I'd suggest you (try) to write code to draw your maze.  You will find your initial grid is buggered up.

Comment: note this code borrowed from here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation#Mathematica and badly mangled.  Hopefully no one else will waste time trying to fix it. (I cant believe this question hasn't been cloded)

Answer (score 1):

I tracked down your code to the [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation#Mathematica) site, and - by way of thanks for that! -  here's how to use the graph-based alternative for maze generation. This is courtesy of user AlephAlpha:

```
MazeGraph[m_, n_] := 
Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity, grid = GridGraph[{m, n}], 
 visited = {}},
Graph[Range[m n],
 Reap[{AppendTo[visited, #];
     Do[
      If[FreeQ[visited, neighbor], 
       Sow[# <-> neighbor]; #0@neighbor],
      {neighbor, RandomSample@AdjacencyList[grid, #]}]} & @ 
   RandomChoice@VertexList@grid][[2, 1]], 
 GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {m, n}},
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[12], Purple], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> None,
 VertexLabels -> "Name",
 VertexLabelStyle -> White,
 Background -> LightGray,
 ImageSize -> 300]];

 width = height = 8;

 maze = MazeGraph[width, height]
```

[image: maze]

Solutions are easy now that the maze is a graph:

```
path = FindShortestPath[maze, 1, Last[VertexList[maze]]];
solution = Show[
  maze,
  HighlightGraph[
   maze,
   PathGraph[path],
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], White],
   GraphHighlightStyle -> None]
  ];
```

and also easy is to find the deleted walls - here, it's the `GraphDifference` between the original `GridGraph` and the maze:

```
hg = HighlightGraph[
   GridGraph[{width, height}, 
    EdgeStyle -> 
     Directive[Opacity[0.2], Blue, AbsoluteThickness[1]]],
   EdgeList[GraphDifference[GridGraph[{width, height}], maze]],
   Background -> LightGray,
   ImageSize -> 300,
   GraphHighlightStyle -> {"Thick"}];
```

Showing all three:

```
Row[{Labeled[maze, "maze"], Spacer[12], Labeled[hg, "deleted walls"], 
  Labeled[solution, "solution"]}]
```

[image]

Apologies for the styling issues - this is the hard part of using graphs... :)

Comment: shouldn't the path be between the walls? (just comparing against the rosetta code version) ..

Comment: @george as I saw it, the walls are gray, the corridors are purple, the solution is white. So the deleted walls are actually deleted corridors.. :)